# How to map the data in the columns type "dropdown" source in react handsontable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, handsontable

```
<HotTable root="hot" ref="hot" settings={this.state.settings} width="100%" strechH="all"/>

this.state = {
    settings: {
        colHeaders:['Packages'],
        data: [{packages:""}],
        columns: [{ data:"packages", type:'dropdown', source:["Pallet", "Box"] }],
        minSpareRows: 0,
        contextMenu: true,
        rowHeaders:true, 
        manualColumnResize: true,
        columnSorting: true, 
        manualRowResize: true, 
        manualRowMove: true,   
        manualColumnMove: true,
    }
}
```

In the columns as i am using manuall source the data is coming in the dropdown like attached sceenshot.

[image]

But, when I need the data to be populated depends on the response.
the response data i am storing in another state variable called `packagesfortable`

```
if (type == 'PackagesList')
{
    let packageslist = UserStore._getpackagelist() || {};
    this.setState({ packageslist }, ()=>
    {
        this.setState({
            packagesfortable: this.state.packageslist.packings.map(el => el.packageName)
        });
    });
}
```

How to populate the `packagesfortable` state variable data dynamically in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

An instance of the `HotTable` has an [updateSettings](https://handsontable.com/docs/6.1.1/Core.html#updateSettings) method that can be called with options to update the table settings.

If a ref is set in your `HotTable` `React.Element`, the underlying instance can be retrieve by accessing `ref.current.HotInstance`.

The following example fetches users from json placeholder API and updates the columns source setting to an array of usernames returned from the API.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import 'handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.css';
import { HotTable } from '@handsontable/react';

const COLUMN_DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {data: "packages", type: 'dropdown'}

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.hotTableComponent = React.createRef();

    this.settings = {
        colHeaders: ['Packages'],
        data: [{ packages: "" }],
        columns: [{ ...COLUMN_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, source: ["Pallet", "Box"] }],
        // ...other settings continue here
     }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      },
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      const usernames = json.map(({username}) => username);
      this.hotTableComponent.current.hotInstance.updateSettings(
        {"columns": [{ ...COLUMN_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, source: usernames}]}
      )
    })

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="hot-app">
        <HotTable
          ref={this.hotTableComponent}
          settings={this.settings}
          width="600"
          stretchH="all" />
      </div>
    );

  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Instead of "Pallet", "Box" I need only usernames, "Pallet", "Box" these are just static instead of that we need to populate usernames alone

Comment: Initialize columns source option to an empty array if you don't care about the static values, fetch the data in `componentDidMount` and update the columns source option. You could decide not to even render the `HotTable` until data is fetched from the API. That's your call. In any case, the user should be shown some progress indicator that data for the table is being fetched.

Comment: _react3.default.createRef is not a function

Comment: You may want to look to see what version of the React library you're running and the way to create refs in that version looking in the docs.

Comment: 15.6.2 was my react version